# Who was the first to solve the linear first order ODE?

Tags: math-history

Who was first to solve equations of the form $y' + p(t)y = g(t)$?  The method of the integration factor is mildly tricky to students at first, so I imagine there must have been some time spent to come up with that trick.  I know that Bernoulli solved the so called Bernoulli's equation $y' + p(t)y = g(t)y^n$ in 1695, so it must have been some time before that.

Comment: I am not sure if this satisfying, but you might want to have a peek. http://www.math.ou.edu/~mleite/MATH3413_sp11pdf/ODE_History.pdf

Comment: @Amzoti Hey that's great stuff!  Thanks!

Comment: The integrating factor method can be motivated either by brute-force necessity, by it's inclusion in the larger story of integrating factors for exact equations and/or the relation of translational symmetry of the linear ODE from which the integrating factor can be derived. That said, everything except brute force seems much more modern than the Bernoulli equation you mention. So, if I had to guess, I'd say Euler. But, this may be like chasing down the origin of the chain rule... I await answers from those wiser than I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leibniz, in 1694.

Leibniz' method is explained by [Victor Katz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321387007), and it is the familiar integrating factor method with some slight changes in notation. For example, Leibniz defines the integrating factor $u(t)$ as the solution to the equation ${{\rm d}u\over u}=p\,{\rm d}t$, instead of the today more familiar $u(t)={\rm exp}\bigl(\int p(t)\,{\rm d}t\bigr)$.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you